# Always display update notificaion when using Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, updates

I just found this [handy site](https://browser-update.org/customize.html) to display notifications to the users to update their browsers if they are obsolete, but on mi site i need to use HTML 5 and Internet Explorer does not support it

Does any one knows if its possible to always show the notification when using Internet Explorer but allow the reminder cooldown on other browsers??

My code so far is this:

```js
    var $buoop = {required:{e:-4,f:-3,o:-3,s:-1,c:-3},insecure:true,unsupported:true,api:2020.08,text_for_i: {
        'msg':'Tu navegador {brow_name} ya no es soportado.',
        'msgmore': 'Por favor utiliza otro navegador para poder usar nuestro sitio.'
     } };
    function $buo_f(){
     var e = document.createElement("script");
     e.src = "//browser-update.org/update.min.js";
     document.body.appendChild(e);
    };
    try {document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", $buo_f,false)}
    catch(e){window.attachEvent("onload", $buo_f)}
```

Comment: See [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/)

Comment: That was my first approach, but  ---> "...This extension was introduced in IE5, but removed in IE10...", so it can only be used in documents rendered in browsers from IE5 to IE9", and the  website i posted also has the feature to detect old versions of any browsers to encourage the user to upgrade their software

Comment: @Chico3001, Does the JS example I shared below helped you to solve the issue? If yes,  you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Actually no.. because i was looking for a solution using the API of the link i provided, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description it looks like if the user is using any version of the IE browser then you want to show the notification to the user to use any other browser.

I suggest you refer to the example below that may help you to get the desired result.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script> 
         //detects if user uses Internet Explorer 
         //returns version of IE or false, if browser is not IE 
         //Function to detect IE or not 
         function IEdetection() { 
             var ua = window.navigator.userAgent; 
             var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE '); 
             if (msie > 0) { 
                 // IE 10 or older, return version number 
                 return ('Tu navegador IE ' + parseInt(ua.substring( 
                   msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10) + ' ya no es soportado. Por favor utiliza otro navegador para poder usar nuestro sitio.'); 
             } 
             var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/'); 
             if (trident > 0) { 
                 // IE 11, return version number 
                 var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:'); 
                 return ('Tu navegador IE ' + parseInt(ua.substring( 
                   rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10) + ' ya no es soportado. Por favor utiliza otro navegador para poder usar nuestro sitio.'); 
             } 
            
             // User uses other browser 
             return ('Welcome...'); 
         } 
         var result = IEdetection(); 
         document.write(result); 
         
         
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Test page...</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

Output in the IE browser:

[image]

Reference:

[How to check the user is using Internet Explorer in JavaScript?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-the-user-is-using-internet-explorer-in-javascript/)